# sql query working properly but stored procedure output is wrong

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want BrandID corresponding to BrandName input such as 'samsung'.When i tried the query it works properly and returns the corresponding BrandID, but when i write the stored procedure it is returning all the BrandID's corresponding to all Brands.

The Table looks as follows..

[image]

The Query is as follows...
[image]

The Stored Procedure as follows..

[image]

window when executing stored procedure.
[image]

The output is as follows..

[image]

The output should be 1 but it is showing 1 and 2.
solution for this problem...

Comment: Please post code - not pictures. However `WHERE BranName = brandName` - You could as good write `WHERE 1 = 1`.

Comment: Don’t give parameters the same name as columns

Comment: Correct, because (besides table and database names) MySQL is case-invariant. And for tables and databases casing is only relevant because file system objects are created for them and hence the file system rules of the OS apply here.